# Jasper report "Infinite loop creating new page"-error if table of detail band dont fit to 1 page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jrxml-report composed of all basic default bands: headers, detail and footers. My detail band contains three dynamic tables defined as subreports and included to detail band. Other bands contain only static fields. Everything works fine with moderate amount of data, but when there's more data in one jasper-table than that can
fit one page (with small footer sections), jasper studio preview mode will throw following exception:
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Infinite loop creating new page due to column footer overflow.

Exception will be thrown in case there is so many rows in the table that the detail band is totally packed with data and addition of next row on that table would start overflowing on top of he column footer band below the detail band.

I wish that Jasper would be able to continue table printing on next page instead of starting to overflowing on column footer and throwing exceptions. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a way to do this.
I'm not even sure if jasper is able to divide one table into multiple pages?

Any suggestions how to proceed with this issue?

I tried adding page break logic to my table, but it seems to be generating exactly the same inifinite loop error whenever the table reaches the amount of rows I defined to page break logic. Anyway, I would not be that interested to add some hard coded page breaking here - i I think there should be a way to tell Jasper just to continue printing on next page if page gets full.

Thanks,
V

Comment: Check the splitType on the band try to set IMMEDIATE

Comment: Looks like I already had that IMMEDIATE setting in place, so that did not do the trick for me.

Comment: I found one alternative solution to solve my problem, even though it doesnt feel quite perfect. What I did was that I created a new detail-band to my main report and I dedicated this new detail band just for the "problematic" table that was causing "these infinite overflowing loops". After making this change my exception changed from "column footer" to "column header" overflow. As at this point I was still referencing my old subreport from the new detail band, I decided to try defining my table straight in the main reports new detail band. After this everything started to work.

Comment: The problem whit this solution is that I'm losing my subreport that I'm using in many places. My subreport contains only column header-band where the table is defined. I guess that the reason why overflow error came is because of the band I have chosen to place my table in subreport. As far as I remember I first tried to define my subreport in detail-band, but that was causing the table to be replicated as many times as there are rows in the table. Maybe there is some other band that could be used in this situation so that I could still use subreport in this situation?